# Keyboard "Next" button color

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to find out how to get the color of the <kbd>Next</kbd> button on an Android keyboard. It is being set by the OS because on the Kindle Fire it is orange and on the Nexus 7 it is blue.

Is there a system call to get that color?

I would like to use that color in other parts of my apps so it looks like the OS's.

Kindle Fire keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That's defined by the input method (e.g. the keyboard), not the OS (which is why it's different on Kindle vs Android -- Amazon has their own custom keyboard).

It's something you shouldn't try to handle, unless you're writing your own custom keyboard.